# Can't add the plus button in OSGi Apache Felix Web Console to create new configuration instances

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

I use a ManagedServiceFactory to create new instances by the parameters that are included in the configuration files. I want to do it by the **Apache Felix Web Console** but it doesn't give me the plus button to add new configurations. 
I think I am missing something. Could you please help me?
This is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYWqf.jpg) of my Apache Felix Web Console

This is the class that implements **ManagedServiceFactory**

```
@org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component(
        name = "camel_config",
        property = {
                "service.pid=camel",
                "factory=true"
        },
        configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.IGNORE
)
public class ConfigReaderFactory implements ManagedServiceFactory {
    private static final String DELETE_CONDITIONS = "readLock=changed&idempotent=false&noop=true&delete=true";
    private static final String NON_DELETE_CONDITIONS = "noop=true";
    private volatile DependencyManager dependencyManager;
    private final Map<String, Component> components = new HashMap<>();
    private List<String> attributes;
    private List<String> csvTypes;
    private CamelService camel;
    private TypeConverter converter;
    private EventPublisher publisher;
    private String url;
    private String name;
    private int confLine;
    private String endpointType;
    private String ip;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String folder;
    private boolean delete;

    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
    private String email;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.getClass().getName();
    }

    @Override
    public void updated(String pid, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Dictionary props) throws ConfigurationException {
        if (components.containsKey(pid)) {
            return;
        }
        if (props != null) {
            attributes = new ArrayList<>();
            csvTypes = new ArrayList<>();

            int count = 1;
            String configurationLine;
            while ((configurationLine = (String) props.get(Integer.toString(count++))) != null) {
                List<String> values = Utils.getValuesFromLine(configurationLine);
                attributes.add(values.size() >= 1 ? values.get(0) : TypeConverter.NAMELESS);
                csvTypes.add(values.size() >= 2 ? values.get(1) : TypeConverter.NAMELESS);
            }
            confLine = Integer.parseInt((String) props.get(Config.CONFIG_LINE));
            name = (String) props.get(Config.NAME);

            initConfigParameters(pid, props);
            buildURL();
            System.out.println("[URL] " + url);

            try {
                Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
                putParameters(params);
                camel.start(params);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleted(String pid) {
        Component component = components.remove(pid);
        dependencyManager.remove(component);
        component.stop();
    }

    private void buildURL() {
        url = "";
        switch(endpointType) {
        case Constants.FTP:
            url += "ftp://" + username + "@" + ip + "/" + folder + "?";
            if(!password.equals("")) {
                url += "password=" + password + "&";
            }
            break;
        case Constants.FILE:
            url += "file://" + folder + "?";
            break;
        case Constants.EMAIL:
            url += "imaps://imap.gmail.com?username="+email+"&password="+password
                    +"&delete=false&unseen=false";
        }
        if(endpointType.equals(Constants.FTP) || endpointType.equals(Constants.FILE)) {
            if (delete) {
                url += DELETE_CONDITIONS;
            } else {
                url += NON_DELETE_CONDITIONS;
            }
        }
    }

    private void initConfigParameters(String pid, @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Dictionary props) {
        confLine = Integer.parseInt((String) props.get(Config.CONFIG_LINE));
        name = (String) props.get(Config.NAME);
        endpointType = (String) props.get(Config.ENDPOINT_TYPE);
        ip = (String) props.get(Config.IP_ADDRESS);
        username = (String) props.get(Config.USERNAME);
        password = (String) props.get(Config.PASSWORD);
        folder = (String) props.get(Config.FOLDER);
        email = (String) props.get(Config.EMAIL);
        delete = ((String) props.get(Config.DELETE)).equals("true");
        if((String) props.get(Config.LATITUDE)!=null) {
            latitude = Double.parseDouble((String) props.get(Config.LATITUDE));
        } 
        if((String) props.get(Config.LONGITUDE)!=null) {
            longitude = Double.parseDouble((String) props.get(Config.LONGITUDE));
        }

        printParameters(pid);
    }
    private void putParameters(Map<String, Object> params) {
        params.put(Constants.ATTRIBUTES, attributes);
        params.put(Constants.TYPES, csvTypes);
        params.put(Constants.CONF_LINE, confLine);
        params.put(Constants.SOURCE, name);
        params.put(Constants.PUBLISHER, publisher);
        params.put(Constants.CONVERTER, converter);
        params.put(Constants.LATITUDE, latitude);
        params.put(Constants.LONGITUDE, longitude);
        params.put(Constants.ENDPOINT_TYPE, endpointType);
        params.put(Constants.EMAIL, email);
        params.put(Constants.CONTEXT, FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass()).getBundleContext());
        Processor processor = new CSVProcessor(params);
        params.put(Constants.PROCESSOR, processor);
        params.put(Constants.URL, url);
    }
    private void printParameters(String pid) {
        System.out.println("\nStarting camel with parameters:");
        System.out.println("Config file name "+pid);
        System.out.println("[sensor_name]::" + name);
        if(latitude!=null && longitude!=null) {
            System.out.println("[latitude]::" + latitude);
            System.out.println("[longitude]::" + longitude);
        }
        System.out.println("[endpoint_type]::" + endpointType);
        if(endpointType.equals("ftp")) {
            System.out.println("[ip_address]::" + ip);
            System.out.println("[folder]::" + folder);
            System.out.println("[user]::" + username);
            System.out.println("[password]::" + password);
        } else if(endpointType.equals("file")) {
            System.out.println("[folder]::" + folder);
        } else if(endpointType.equals("email")) {
            System.out.println("[email]::" + email);
            System.out.println("[password]::" + password);
        }
        System.out.println("[delete]::" + delete);
    }

    @Reference(service = TypeConverter.class)
    public void setTypeConverter(TypeConverter converter) {
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    public void unsetTypeConverter(TypeConverter converter) {
        this.converter = null;
    }

    @Reference(service = EventPublisher.class)
    public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public void unsetEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = null;
    }

    @Reference(service = CamelService.class)
    public void setCamelService(CamelService camel) {
        this.camel = camel;
    }

    public void unsetCamelService(CamelService camel) {
        this.camel = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I use a ManagedServiceFactory to create new instances by the parameters that are included in the configuration files.

You are using Declarative Services (your class is annotated `@Component`) but also implementing ManagedServiceFactory. As others have mentioned this is a bad practice and you should not do it. Furthermore your code is not thread safe, and the `Map<String, Component> components` could become corrupted.

A far better solution is to follow the recommendation of making the Component `configurationPolicy=ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE` and using an `@Activate` method to receive configuration and an `@Destroy` method to handle deletions. You then don't need the maps at all.

> I want to do it by the Apache Felix Web Console but it doesn't give me the plus button to add new configurations.

The Felix Web console is using Metatype to generate this user interface. Writing Metatype XML is horrible, and should not be attempted by humans, but fortunately you can use the `org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations` to define your metatype. These annotations are applied to an interface or an annotation which describes the layout of your configuration. For example:

```
@ObjectClassDefinition
public @interface MyConfig {

    // This defines the property key "myProp" with
    // a default value of "foo" and it will show
    // up in the UI with the name "My Prop"
    String myProp() default "foo";

    // This defines the property key "my.prop"
    // with a default value of 42. The @AD
    // allows customisation of the UI
    @AD(description="Something descriptive")
    int my_num() default 42;
}
```

You link this configuration property type with your component using the @Designate annotation:

```
@org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component(
    name = "camel_config", configurationPid=camel",
    configurationPolicy = ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE
)
@Designate(ocd=MyConfig.class)
public class ConfigReaderFactory {
    ...
}
```

When using DS 1.3 you can also inject this configuration type directly into your activate method.

```
@Activate
void activate(MyConfig config) {
    // process config...
}
```

You can also inject the Map as well if you like:

```
@Activate
void activate(MyConfig config, Map<String, Object> rawConfig) {
    // process config...
}
```

Once your metatype is defined the `+` icon will appear, along with a custom UI for configuring your component.

Comment: it solved my problem. I really thank you, I think I will solve my confusion about DS annotations soon

Answer (score 0):

There may be something I don't know, but AFAIK you can not create new instances of managed services via [Configuration Admin Service](http://enroute.osgi.org/services/org.osgi.service.cm.html) (which is what the web-console configuration uses).

`ManagedServiceFactory` is a factory which you (or the framework on your behalf) call to create a service on demand. You can use Configuration Admin Service to configure the factory itself but it is the factory that is responsible for configuring the service instances it creates.

On the other hand you can use [Metatype service](http://enroute.osgi.org/services/org.osgi.service.metatype.html) to describe the configuration of any non-managed service. If you do that, then tools like Felix Web Console and Apache File Install can use that information to create new instances of your service when new configuration is provided. This is when you see the plus button in Felix Web Console Configuration screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to implement `ManagedServiceFactory` at all. To get
components that are created multiple times, i.e. one instance per Config Admin
record. You only need to create a plain component with a
configurationPolicy of "require". For example:

```java
@Component(name = "camel, configurationPolicy=ConfigurationPolicy.REQUIRE)
public class ConfigReaderComponent {

    @Activate
    void activate(Map<String, Object> configProps) {
        // process config...
    }
}
```

This whole class will be instantiated once for each Configuration Record with
the factory PID of `camel`. And WebConsole will be aware that it is a factory and will enable the plus button.